# Access Query Dlookup not returning value #error

Tags: ms-access, vba, iif

Trying to be short and sweet, my problem is a #Error given by the following function in an Access Query when trying to fill in relative information for a FEDWire or International Wire:

```
IIf(IsNull([BeneABA]),DLookUp("Code","tblCountryCodes","[Country]=" & [Intl_BeneBankCountry]),DLookUp("State","qryFEDWIRE","RoutingNumber=" & [BeneABA]))
```

This works successfully when BeneABA is filled in. It returns the correct "State" given the ABA/Routing information of the Bank. The idea is to pull the 2 digit country "Code" when ABA is null (an international wire will have a swiftID and therefore not an ABA).

As I have shown in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USVD8.png) and this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pSo5.png), I get #Error when there is no BeneABA. In this example, the #Error should actually be "HK" pulled from tblCountryCodes where it looked for "Hong Kong" and returned the "Code"

Here is the relationship builder from the query with relevant tables: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddi4z.png)

does anyone have any advice or know of a better way to populate this field with Code if a user puts in the country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Country is text try adding some quotes around the criteria;

```
IIf(IsNull([BeneABA]),DLookUp("Code","tblCountryCodes","[Country]='" & [Intl_BeneBankCountry] & "'"),DLookUp("State","qryFEDWIRE","RoutingNumber=" & [BeneABA]))
```

You'll need to do the same around your RoutingNumber if that is text and not a number.

You could also wrap the lookups in Nz() function to handle a null return more elegantly.

```
Nz(DLookup(...),"No Value")
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but could also use `DLookUp("Code","tblCountryCodes","[Country]=" & NZ([Intl_BeneBankCountry],1))` which will return a default country code of 1 if Intl_BeneBankCountry is Null.

Comment: Ahh yes the field in question is a text field. I added the " ' " and it worked! Successfully pulling the correct country code from the underlying table. Thanks!